# Is there a way to identify and convert nonescaped four-digit Unicode characters within a string of normal characters?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, python-unicode, unicode-string

I'm using requests.get to retrieve data from Google Ngrams.

I'm having a problem where, when I query the website for a string with an accent character in it (in this case I'm searching `"marcher d'un pas lourd"`), it returns information for `"marcher d&#39; un pas lourd"`.

As you can see in the returned string, the apostrophe has been replaced with the four-digit Unicode for an apostrophe.

This messes up the rest of my code, as I use my original string query (`"marcher d'un pas lourd"`) to find the data I need from the returned data.

Is there any function or program that will search and convert four-digit Unicode in a string of otherwise normal characters? Note that I DO NOT want to remove these special characters, but rather get them to their correct representation within my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are call HTML entities, and they can be unescaped with:

```
>>> s="marcher d&#39; un pas lourd"
>>> import html
>>> html.unescape(s)
"marcher d' un pas lourd"
```